# Full Text Search with Multiple columns

Tags: sql, full-text-search

My actual requirement was to search column value with another column value,

```
SELECT L.PostID FROM Latest L
CROSS JOIN TempAssociateSkillsData Skills
    WHERE 
**L.ContentDescription** LIKE '%'+**Skills.SkillName**+'%'
```

I tried with full Text search

```
create fulltext catalog DBSkillName
create fulltext Index on Latest(
    ContentDescription language 1033,
    ContentTitle language 1033
)
key index pk_Id
on DBSkillName
with change_tracking auto


SELECT L.PostID FROM Latest L
CROSS JOIN TempAssociateSkillsData Skills
    WHERE 
    contains(L.ContentDescription ,Skills.SkillName)
```

But throwing below error

[Full Text search with multiple columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOAst.png)

Advanced Thanks
Abdul Aleem S

Comment: A CROSS JOIN with join conditions in the WHERE clause should be an INNER JOIN. (This works too, but is weird.)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The fulltext functionality you're using is a product specific feature.)